# Use a Datagrid in a DatagridComboboxColumn Body in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with 7 columns. One of the columns must be a combobox, when user clicks on the combobox, a form or a panel must be shown with a datagrid inside it. The second datagrid has some columns and must have editable rows and etc.
How can I implement this in DatagridColumn ?
The information are given in the picture :
[Datagrid in combobox body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67lyp.png)

Or is there a component which I can use to implement something like this ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you considered DataGrids RowDetails where you can have another DataGrid?

Comment: RowDetails is a full row that opens below the current row. But what I want is a cell below the current cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a DataGridTemplateColumn and then add a editing template with a Popup panel with another DataGrid.

This is an example with this solution.

- Double click in the "Tot.Quantity" cell to show Popup.
- Click on other cell to close the Popup.
- Changing the quantity in the Popup, affect the "Tot.Quantity" value when you close the Popup.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SODataGridInComboBox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SODataGridInComboBox"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalQuantity}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
                </DataTemplate>
                <!--DataTemplate when in edit mode. -->
                <DataTemplate x:Key="EditingMyTemplate" DataType="ProductPartList">
                    <Popup IsOpen="True">
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding PartList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding PartId}"/>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Popup>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Grid.Resources>
            <DataGrid Name="DG1" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
                    <!--Custom column that shows the part list-->
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Tot.Quantity" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MyTemplate}" CellEditingTemplate="{StaticResource EditingMyTemplate}" />
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;

namespace SODataGridInComboBox
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Product> Products { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Product>();

        private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Products.Add(
                new Product()
                {
                    Id = "Prod1",
                    PartList = new List<ProductPartList>()
                    {
                        new ProductPartList() { PartId = "p11", Quantity=3},
                        new ProductPartList() { PartId = "p12", Quantity=2}
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public List<ProductPartList> PartList { get; set; }
        public int TotalQuantity => PartList?.Sum(p => p.Quantity) ?? 0;
    }

    public class ProductPartList
    {
        public string PartId { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }
}
```